# Write regex for below format

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

Can you please help to write regex for below current format to expected format.

Current format data:

```
web_add_auto_header("Origin",  
      "http://eesere6090582.loot.welcome.com:8888");
web_add_auto_header("Wicket-Ajax",  
      "true");
web_add_auto_header("Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL",  
      "servers?1");
web_add_auto_header("Wicket-FocusedElementId",  
      "id40");
web_add_auto_header("X-Requested-With",  
      "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Expected format:

```
web_add_auto_header("Origin","http://eesere6090582.loot.welcome.com:8888");
web_add_auto_header("Wicket-Ajax","true");
web_add_auto_header("Wicket-Ajax-BaseURL","servers?1");
web_add_auto_header("Wicket-FocusedElementId","id40");
web_add_auto_header("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Sorry for adding image, tried to put the code directly unfortunately it was erroring out. hence tried adding image here

Comment: There is no need to change these.  LoadRunner will process both statements the same way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use regex `^(web_add_auto_header.*,)\n\s*` with replacement `$1`.

It will replace newlines after strings beginning with `web_add_auto_header`.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/JOUQXC/2) is demo at regex101.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the empty space at the start of the strings could be tab(s) or multiple single spaces, .. you're regex could look like :

```
",\n\s+"   replace with   "\,"
```

https://regex101.com/r/7J4sC7/1

Comment: is there any way we can add groups like below
web_add_auto_header(.*?)",\n\s+","(.*?));

I have to add "Web_add_auto_header in search" because i don't want any other function to get update except which is starting with web_add_auto_header

Comment: Why do you escape coma in replacement string?